# Using '.' (dot or period) in an XPath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

Can someone tell me the difference between the following XPath expressions?

```
/IntuitResponse/QueryResponse/Bill/./Id
/IntuitResponse/QueryResponse/Bill/Id
```

I've tried using both to parse an XML document from the document root and I'm getting the same response.

Comment: Like in DOS directories, `.` is the current directory. Those XPaths are identical. You can even do `./Id/../Id/./../Id`  and things like that

Comment: So `.` is only useful if we're starting the parsing from a different context? If I traverse to `/IntuitResponse/QueryResponse/Bill`, then make a new call to `evaluate` using the current `Node` as the context, `./Id` works (it returns the `Id` of the first `/IntuitResponse/QueryResponse/Bill/`) but `/Id` doesn't.

Comment: With `/` you start at the root node again, so use `./Id` or just `Id` from the Bill node on.

Comment: I was actually a bit surprised when `/Id` didn't work. I thought it would consider the start of the data in the current `Node` as the root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Those two XPaths are equivalent.**

The abbreviation for `self::node()` (`.`) is more useful ***within a predicate***.  For example,

```
/IntuitResponse/QueryResponse/Bill/Id[. = 'abc']
```

would select only those `Id` elements whose string value is `'abc'`.

Also, `.` is useful to introduce a ***relative path***.  For example,

```
./Id
```

would select only those `Id` elements that are a child of the current context node.